# Getting error while uploading mkv files to AWS s3 bucket using react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload large files to AWS s3 bucket. I am successfully able to upload files with extension .mp4/.jpeg/.png. But i am getting error while uploading .mkv extension.

```
//CODE to check file type
function checkFileType( file, cb ){
 // Allowed ext
 const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|mkv|mp4/;
 // Check ext
 const extname = filetypes.test( path.extname( file.originalname ).toLowerCase());
 // Check mime
 const mimetype = filetypes.test( file.mimetype );
if( mimetype && extname ){
  return cb( null, true );
 } else {
  cb( 'Error: Videos Only!' );
 }
}
```

Any idea? why

Comment: Well...what's the error!?

Comment: As I add error section on else part. Error: Videos only

Comment: so it looks to me like your file is lacking a mimeType.  It's hard to tell from only looking at this small snippet of code.  What is calling the `checkFIleType` function?